# Improve parse html code with DOM with PHP

Tags: php, html

I created the following code to display a blank page , a piece of an external site , but I had to remove some nodes and each node needed to create a piece of code and it made almost unfeasible his maintenance if it was a big project.

My doubts:

1. Is there a way to put in a single stretch all we want to eliminate ( footer , header , headerContent , etc.)?
2. Is there a smarter way to clean instead of deleting elements, just show what I want ( TABLE1 )?

   ```
           # Create a DOM parser object
           $dom = new DOMDocument();
           libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
           $dom->loadHTMLFile('http://www.sptrans.com.br/sac/solicitacoes.aspx');
           $data = $dom -> getElementByid('TABELA1');


           $xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
           foreach($xpath->query('//div[contains(attribute::id, "novidadeDestaque")]') as $e ) {
               // Delete this node
               $e->parentNode->removeChild($e);
           }

           $xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
           foreach($xpath->query('//div[contains(attribute::id, "headerLvl1")]') as $e ) {
               // Delete this node
               $e->parentNode->removeChild($e);
           }

           $xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
           foreach($xpath->query('//div[contains(attribute::id, "headerContent")]') as $e ) {
               // Delete this node
               $e->parentNode->removeChild($e);
           }

           $xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
           foreach($xpath->query('//div[contains(attribute::id, "novo_menu")]') as $e ) {
               // Delete this node
               $e->parentNode->removeChild($e);
           }
           $xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
           foreach($xpath->query('//div[contains(attribute::id, "footer")]') as $e ) {
               // Delete this node
               $e->parentNode->removeChild($e);
           }
           $xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
           foreach($xpath->query('//div[contains(attribute::id, "header")]') as $e ) {
               // Delete this node
               $e->parentNode->removeChild($e);
           }       
           $xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
           foreach($xpath->query('//div[contains(attribute::id, "pageNovidades")]') as $e ) {
               // Delete this node
               $e->parentNode->removeChild($e);
           }   

               echo $dom->saveHTML();                          
                   ?>
   </body>
   ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a **short-code** routine to eliminate desired elements you can use an array:

```
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$idToDelete = [ 'novidadeDestaque', 'headerLvl1', ... ];

foreach( $idToDelete as $id )
{
    foreach($xpath->query('//div[contains(attribute::id, "'.$id.'")]') as $e ) {
        $e->parentNode->removeChild($e);
    }
}
```

Please note that you don't need to create a new `DOMXPath` object for each search: you can create it only once per `DOMDocument` object.

To **show only what you want,** you can use this syntax:

```
$table = $dom->GetElementById( 'MyTable' );
echo $dom->saveHTML( $table );
```

To have a **complete HTML** with only desired table, you can create a new `DOMDocument` and use `importNode` to add your table:

```
$src = new DOMDocument();
$dst = new DOMDocument();

$src->loadHTML( $html );
$dst->loadHTML( '<html><head><title>Untitled</title></head><body></body></html>' );

$table    = $src->GetElementById( 'MyTable' );
$imported = $dst->importNode( $table );

$dst->getElementsByTagName( 'body' )->item(0)->appendChild( $imported );

$dst->saveHTML();
```

---

- Read more about [DOMDocument::importNode](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.importnode.php)